# Sonar produces high issue for the code checkstyle related to collection

Tags: java

I am using Sonar in my application and getting the issue as ; Empty arrays and collections should be returned instead of null. Here is my code where i am trying to pass an empty list but getting

**error as "Incompatible types Required: java.lang.Class[] found: java.util.list"**

```
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
     return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

Comment: change it to return new Class[0]

Comment: Updated text formatting

Answer (score 0):

Yes, well...

```
 protected Class[] getRootConfigClasses() { return new Class[]{}; }
```

This returns empty array and should be type compatible

Comment: You shouldn't create a new array every time the method is called just make one and then use that every time.

Answer (score 0):

The method expects a return type of an *Array* of `Class`, you are returning an empty `List`, which is entirely different from an Array.

Return an empty array instead:

```
protected Class[] getRootConfigClasses() { return new Class[0]; }
```